# Can't pickle _thread.lock objects Pyspark send request to elasticseach

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am using pyspark streaming to collect data from tweepy. After all the set up, I send the dict(json) to elasticsearch via elasticsearch.index(). But I get "can't pickle_thread.lock objects" error and other 63 errors. The track back log is too long to show in my console!

The design is that I get a json/dict type file, convert it into an DStream, add another feature names "sentiment" to it by calling TextBlob in a map() function. It all works fine, but when I add another map function to call elasticsearch.index(), I get the error.

Below is the part of the super long error log in my console.

> Blockquote
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/ayane/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 105, in dumps
>       func.func, func.rdd_wrap_func, func.deserializers)))
>     File "/Users/ayane/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 460, in dumps
>       return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
>     File "/Users/ayane/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 704, in dumps
>       cp.dump(obj)
>     File "/Users/ayane/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 162, in dump
>       raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
>   _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonTransformFunctionSerializer$.serialize(PythonDStream.scala:144)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonDStream.scala:101)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
>       ... 63 more

Part of my code looks like this:

```
def sendPut(doc):
  res = es.index(index = "tweetrepository", doc_type= 'tweet', body = doc)
  return doc
myJson = dataStream.map(decodeJson).map(addSentiment).map(sendPut)
myJson.pprint()
```

Here is the decodeJson function:

```
def decodeJson(str):
  return json.loads(str)
```

Here is the addSentiment function:

```
def addSentiment(dic):
  dic['Sentiment'] = get_tweet_sentiment(dic['Text'])
  return dic
```

And here is the get_tweet_sentiment function:

```
def get_tweet_sentiment(tweet):
  analysis = TextBlob(tweet)
  if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
    return 'positive'
  elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
    return 'neutral'
  else:
    return 'negative'
```

Comment: Where is the output of pprint() ?

Comment: If I remove the last map(sendPut) function, the output will be:
{"Text": "Hello from the XXXXX", "Loc": "123.00, 25.36", "Timestamp" : "20180418125154", "Sentiment": "positive"}

Comment: Need to see types, because some data types are non-pickleable objects. Give us more information, and separate out your mapping functions.

Comment: TextBlob is an API for NLP.

Comment: I know what TextBlob is and it's a non-pickleable object. Separate out your mapping and tell me if you get an error at SendPut?

Comment: Yes, it all works fine until it comes to the sendPut. I am confused. TextBlob is an api function, not an object, I think. The DStream RDD should contain str, such as "positive", "negative" as the value of "Sentiment", right?

Comment: Just tried remove the addSentiment map, I still get the same error message :(

Comment: Do the addSentiment map, but don't do the SendPut map. And show what myJson looks like after that. Request you to add it in the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connections objects in general, are not serializable so cannot be passed by closure. You have to use [`foreachPartition` pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd):

```
def sendPut(docs):
    es = ... # Initialize es object
    for doc in docs
        es.index(index = "tweetrepository", doc_type= 'tweet', body = doc)

myJson = (dataStream
    .map(decodeJson)
    .map(addSentiment)
    # Here you need an action.
    # `map` is lazy, and `pprint` doesn't guarantee complete execution
    .foreachPartition(sendPut))
```

If you want to return something use `mapPartitions`:

```
def sendPut(docs):
    es = ... # Initialize es object
    for doc in docs
        yield es.index(index = "tweetrepository", doc_type= 'tweet', body = doc)


myJson = (dataStream
   .map(decodeJson)
   .map(addSentiment)
   .mapPartitions(sendPut))
```

but you'll need an additional action to force execution.

Comment: Awesome! Problem solved. The problem is that I need to initialize es inside the function, not as a global variable. Otherwise, I will need to broadcast the es.